# Reduce multiple foreach loops in code C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I have wrote a really messy code, just because I did not had an idea how to loop through the multiple list of objects.

Code is working what it suppose to do, but I am not confident with it. 
Does someone has an idea how this kind of code can be refactored so it is more readable?

```
foreach (var outlet in merchant.Outlets)
{
    if (outlet != null)
    {
        foreach (var terminal in merchant.Terminals)
        {
            if (terminal != null)
            {
                foreach (var agreement in terminal.AssociateAgreements)
                {
                    var bankInfo = new Bank();
                    if (agreement != null)
                    {
                        bankInfo.UniqueID = AgreementUniqueCode + agreement.ID;
                        bankInfo.BankBIC = agreement.BankAccountInformation.SwiftBIC;
                        bankInfo.BankName = agreement.BankAccountInformation.BankName;
                        bankInfo.Address =
                            AddressEntityToAddress(agreement.BankAccountInformation.BankAddress,
                                BankingType);

                        bankInfo.type = BankType;
                    }
                    banksAccountInformation.Add(bankInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use methods. You may add a method to Outlet such as ProcessTerminals, and one to Terminal such as ProcessAgreements.

Comment: You might want to put this question in 'Code Review' stackoverflow, not really appropriate here.

Comment: You could also remove the if conditions to match with NULL, because foreach loop always itreate on values in the collection and collection doesn't have the NULL insertions.

Comment: @Shubhit304: Foreach loops also process null values and collection may contain null values. Therfore the null check is correct.

Comment: @JNS: this happens only if the collection is of user defined datatype in which user manages the collection and fill it by values. Other wise I dont think .net will return you any collection having NULL values in between collections total count objects.

Comment: @Shubhit304: You are right, it's not very likely that the collections contain null values. But actually we dont know enough about the code and it is technical possible so IMHO it is not OK to suggest to remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use the linq query syntax:

```
var outletQuery = from outlet in merchant.Outlets
                  where outlet != null
                  select outlet;

var agreementQuery = from terminal in merchant.Terminals
                     where terminal != null
                     from agreement in terminal.AssociateAgreements
                     select agreement;

foreach (var outlet in outletQuery)
{
    foreach (var agreement in agreementQuery)
    {
       ProcessAgreement(agreement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use LINQ, especially `SelectMany` and `Where`:

```
List<Bank> banksAccountInformation = merchant
    .Where(m => m.Outlets != null && m.Terminals != null)
    .SelectMany(m => m.Terminals
        .SelectMany(t => t.AssociateAgreements
            .Where(aa => aa != null)
            .Select(aa => new Bank
            {
                UniqueID = AgreementUniqueCode + aa.ID
                // ...
            })))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If the only thing you want to is drilling down the object hierarchy, then you can use [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) or linq:

```
// here you get a flattened collection of Terminals
merchants.SelectMany( m => m.Terminals)
// here you get a flattened collection of all AssociateAgreements of all Terminals
   .SelectMany( t => t.AssociateAgreements)
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am:

```
foreach (var outlet in merchant.Outlets)
{
    if (outlet == null)
        continue;

    foreach (var terminal in merchant.Terminals)
    {
        if (terminal == null)
            continue;

        foreach (var agreement in terminal.AssociateAgreements)
        {
            if (agreement == null)
                continue;

            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the code as well while posting an answer.